# National Referendums

Tags: united-states, voting, census

What is the process for an ordinary citizen to get a national referendum on the ballot?

An example might be: All voting districts must be determined by a grid system thus creating a uniform system of redrawing districts for the entire USA.

Follow up questions:

1. Can ordinary citizens propose national referendums?
2. Is there any history of ordinary citizens getting national referendums on the ballot?

Comment: Welcome to Law SE. Are you asking about a specific jurisdiction, and should this be asked in Law SE or Politics SE?

Comment: National of which nation? There is more than one nation in the world...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I apologize. I should have specified the United States. It really isn't a political question in that I am interested in knowing what ordinary citizens are able to do. 

The specific problem is that there are those who believe that a national system of setting districts with a grid system is preferable to our system of allowing local setting of districts. I suppose there are political inferences. So I understand. I am just interested in learning what is legal. 

Thanks again for your answers. they have been helpful.

Answer (score 7):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

> What is the process for an ordinary citizen to get a national
> referendum on the ballot?

It can't be done. There are no national referendums in the United States and there is no means by which they can be held.

Many states individually provide for state initiatives, referendums, and recall votes (and sometimes even local ones), but this doesn't exist at the national level.

On rare occasions, Congress passes a law calling for a referendum on terms of its choosing in territory outside of any U.S. state, usually on the issue of whether that state shall become a state or otherwise change its legal status. The most recent one was in Puerto Rico. These also cannot be proposed or placed on the ballot by ordinary citizens, and are sometimes binding, but sometimes only advisory in nature.

> 1. Can ordinary citizens propose national referendums?

No.

> 2. Is there any history of ordinary citizens getting national referendums on the ballot?

No.